# Drupal 7 File Upload Field Empty

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a problem on a site that I manage where users can't upload files because the file attachments section doesn't show any inputs:

[image: Broken prod environment]

The exact same code on our dev environment works as expected, with pretty much the same database:

[image: Working dev environment]

I suspect that the problem has to do with file permissions or upload size restrictions, but I'm not sure.

Drupal documentation on this, and forums, are pretty sparse. Any ideas?

---

Edit: I'm seeing this error message in the status report. Maybe it's related?

[image: Potentiall]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everyone. The answer to this problem was much simpler than I had expected--we just had to clear the Drupal cache. It was complicated by the fact that we didn't have full control over the production server, but once we cleared the cache from the browser everything was working again. Hope that helps anyone who runs into a similar situation.

Clearing the cache should be one of the first steps for addressing Drupal issues it seems! Should have thought of it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration (file_uploads = On must be set to "On")

PHP configuration:

For file uploads to work, PHP must be configured properly. The following PHP configuration variables may need to be set or configured, in your PHP php.ini file, .htaccess file, or settings.php files.

```
file_uploads = On must be set to "On"
upload_max_filesize = 24M can't be larger than post_max_size
max_input_time = 300 small values may cause timeouts for large file uploads
memory_limit = 64M small values may cause out of memory errors for large file 
uploads
max_execution_time = 180 small values may cause timeouts for large file uploads
post_max_size = 24M limits the size of input submitted to the website (including 
attached files)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the file_uploads option in the configurations menu. I'm guessing it needs to happen in the php.ini file?

Comment: exactly, check the php.ini this is the servers configuration not the CMS config.

Comment: If you didn't resolve your problem, you could check if the gd php library is enabled in your server.

Comment: Not yet. I just got the php info file. file_uploads is set to on. One difference I notice between prod and dev is the upload_tmp_dir. On dev, it's set to no value, whereas on prod it's set to D:\php_temp. Do you think that could be the issue? Also, max_execution_time is only 60, but that shouldn't cause the input to disappear altogether.

Comment: hm, upload_tmp_dir is usually inside projects root folder project/tmp

max_execution_time is not creating a problem for you surly but you need to increase  those numbers. Did you check Danielas comment is GD Support enabled? Do a full comparison of configuration on dev and live: project/admin/reports/status/php

Comment: Yup GD is enabled on both environments. Is it safe to unset the upload_tmp_dir?

Comment: Better to create it inside your root folder and add permissions to be writable by a web server than change the path inside php.ini  (set permission and ownership on tmp folder).

Comment: I think that is the issue drupal by default looks at project/tmp if you go here
yoursite/admin/config/media/file-system   you will see where your drupal looks at i tmp directory default is /tmp so yes go ahead and create a folder there, set permissions and ownership and change the php.ini > upload_tmp_dir

Comment: Any news Roger? I think we finally detected the issue in last comments.

Comment: Thanks @Beyer. Not yet. I'm working with our server manager to find out the permissions on the tmp directory. Our production server is a Windows machine. Do you think there would be any difference there?

Comment: @RogerWang check apache configuration to ROOT /tmp is not at the same place in production (linux ?)

Answer (score 0):

In back-end go to Configuration -> Media -> File system and just hit "Save configuration" button without changing anything. If there is a problem with some path (not writable) it's field will get red outline.

Comment: That message means that server doesn't allow Drupal to access external pages, i.e. to check for updates or do the updates, fetch external content and similar. Should not be related to this issue, but should be fixed for sure.

Comment: I tried doing the save configuration in the File System menu, and... no errors.

Comment: Then problem is somewhere else. Not in non writable folders.